# An app I thought I deleted starts on login and creates a folder in my home directory, how to stop this?

Tags: fedora, launcher

Update: Solved! See the bottom for what I did.

To use a university's VPN, I tried to install the official GlobalProtect client for linux (I'm using Fedora, so I followed the Red Hat instructions). It kept crashing and didn't work, so I found an open source alternative that works fabulously. Now, I wanted to delete the official client.

The official instructions for removing it didn't include instructions for Red Hat / Fedora, so I tried to manually find all the files I downloaded or the installer created and delete them.

This mostly worked. The app no longer shows up in Application Launcher on KDE Plasma, and the command to start the CLI version isn't recognized. But every time I log in, the first thing I see is a pop up to use the GUI for the official GlobalProtect client. It looks slightly different from the open source one, so I know it's the one I tried to delete. It also creates a folder `.GlobalProtect` in my Home directory.

I tried deleting the `.GlobalProtect` folder, but it reappeared when I rebooted.

How can I get rid of this? I can live with the hidden file in my Home directory, but I'd really like to not see the app GUI every time I reboot. What might be triggering the launch? I couldn't find anything in my `.bashrc` file, which is the only place I know to look for things that happen on login.

(Please let me know if there's a better set of tags to use, I'm unsure.)

**Solution**

I got the idea from @waltinator to search for other places where autostart things might be stored. There is another, `/etc/xdg/autostart/`. In it, I found a file called something like `PanGPUI.desktop`. When I opened that file, it pointed to another directory in `/opt`, which contained all sorts of stuff related to running the GlobalProtect client. Deleting both the file in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and the directory in `/opt`, which I did through the terminal since they required sudo privileges, solved my problem.

Comment: You should also look in `~/.config/autostart/`,. These get executed at GUI login time.

Comment: Check your startup applications and remove the app if it is there.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow to [install GlobalProtect App for Linux](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/download-and-install-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux)? ... and did you try the recommended [uninstall directions](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/globalprotect/5-1/globalprotect-app-user-guide/globalprotect-app-for-linux/uninstall-the-globalprotect-app-for-linux)?

Comment: @waltinator That folder is empty. Are there other, similar folders that I could check?

Comment: @elmo I've checked in Plasma's settings (using the GUI) and it isn't there, is there a more thorough way to check?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I believe that I followed the GUI instructions on the page that you linked, although it's possible that I did a few things from the CLI instructions as well. However, it's the remnants of the GUI that are giving me problems.  I looked at the recommended uninstall directions (the same ones you linked to) but they're only for Debian systems as far as I can tell since they use `dpkg` and `apt`. I'm running Fedora, so I couldn't follow those instructions.

Comment: Why don't you re-install and then un-instal, this time using the steps recommended in the the same website.

Comment: Rather than updating your Question with the solution, post it as an Answer, and click the checkmark to Accept it.

Comment: What's the output of `dnf list the_global_protect_package_name_from_the_rpm`?  Does it show it is installed?  If so, use `dnf` to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the idea from @waltinator to search for other places where autostart things might be stored. There is another, /etc/xdg/autostart/. In it, I found a file called something like PanGPUI.desktop. When I opened that file, it pointed to another directory in /opt, which contained all sorts of stuff related to running the GlobalProtect client. Deleting both the file in /etc/xdg/autostart/ and the directory in /opt, which I did through the terminal since they required sudo privileges, solved my problem.